# 'Could not find a part of the path ...' error in asp.net mvc application

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have reviewed the other posts about this topic and haven't found a solution. This exception is thrown on the production server in an Azure Web App, but not on a local development machine.

```
     public async Task<ActionResult> ProcessConfigFile(int projectModelId, HttpPostedFileBase file)
      {
        string dateTimeStamp = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmssffff");

        string fileLocation = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/") + dateTimeStamp + projectModelId.ToString() + Request.Files["file"].FileName;

        //save file in fileLocation
        Request.Files["file"].SaveAs(fileLocation);

          //other work....
      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the App_Data folder that shows up in Visual Studio was empty,  and subsequently had never been published to the server in Azure, even though it exists in the directory on my local development hard drive.

Once I added a meaningless .txt file to the App_Data folder, the folder was created on the production server and everything works.